# TextEdit Text Input Issues in my game

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android game and am currently trying to get text input working. I want to prompt the player to enter his or her name and have that name added to the high score list.

I am trying to do that through EditText which I can get to work if I put my code in the onCreate method, but not if I call it from my game loop.

The method I am currently using:

```
public static void getInput(Context context)
{
    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    final EditText input = new EditText(context);

    alert.setView(input);
    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
        {
            String value = input.getText().toString().trim();
        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    alert.show();
}
```

If I call this from my gameloop the game crashes and I get the error:

```
01-26 06:33:21.413: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6960): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

I tried calling Looper.prepare() and then Looper.loop(), and that opened up the text input box, but when I closed the box my game just sat on a black screen and did not respond.

So, my question is: what am I doing wrong, and is there an easier way to get text input? My game is based off the LunarLander example, so I am using SurfaceView.

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: How are you calling getinput?

Comment: I am calling it from inside the surfaceview by "Main.getInput(getContext());"
EDIT: Main being my main activity class.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to do UI (showing a dialog) from a thread other than the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Smills:
     your question should thread problem.any change on UI should down with the UI thread.you can use handler to post your intent that prompt users do something . handler in your gameloop function can post a message,and the same handler handlemessage on your UI thread,then change your UI.

the example like this:

declare a global variable:

Handler mHandler;

your function(){

```
 Message msg = Message.obtain();
 msg.what = your flag ;
 handler.post(msg);
```

}

Comment: Hmm, this seems to be the right track, but how do I use a handler to get text input? From what I can tell it seems to only be used to output messages? I think I am not understanding it correctly.

Comment: Ah, I figured it out, I simply used: 

mHandler.post(new Runnable() { 
             public void run() {
              currentName=Main.getInput(getContext());
             }
         });

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You you have access to you activity, try wrapping the dialog code in a runnable and call runOnUiThread(dialogRunnable). Your other options are to start a handler in your activity onCreate and then post a request to the handler. But perhaps you just want to create a dialog activity (and activity using the theme android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog") and just use startActivity.